# paging in grid extjs

Tags: extjs, grid, paging

i want to use the paging toolbar but have one problem. I don't make the service so i need to work with the json i have. The problem is that the format of the json is different then the tutorials.

```
{
"Weather": [{
    "totalCount": 2962,
    some data
           },{
    "totalCount": 2962,
    some data
           }]
}
```

but in the tutorials i saw it should be

```
{
"totalCount": 2962,
"Weather": [{
    some data
           },{
    some data
           }]
}
```

Is there a way i could use the format i have? I tried to do this:

```
proxy: {
      type: 'ajax',
  url: detailURL,
       reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'Weather',
            totalProperty: 'Weather.totalCount'
     }
   },
```

that didn't worked. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your format is wrong, since the total count is inside of each array element. Unfurtunatelly you will need to change your format. You can try something like:

```
// inside your reader (gets the totalCount of the first array element)
totalProperty: 'Weather[0].totalCount'
```

But it really isn't the right choice, since it does not make sense to have each array element with the same count, don't you agree?

Comment: i know it is not the best way but you made me happy with this answer!

Comment: i had to wait for 6 min before i could accept it. This works perfect!